# Firedac + Ingres get QEP

Tags: delphi, odbc, delphi-xe8, firedac, ingres

is there a way to get **QEP** (query execution plan) output from **Firedac** throught ODBC from **Ingres** database?
I tried

```
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('set printqry');
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('set Lock_Trace');
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('set qep');
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('set trace point qe90');
FDConnection1.ExecSQL('set printrules');

FDQuery1.Active:= false;
FDQuery1.SQL.Text:= 'SELECT * FROM airline';

FDQuery1.Prepare;
FDQuery1.Open();
```

but i got nothing about QEP
I need it in my application

**UPDATE1**
After talk with Actian - 
we should set environment variables:

```
II_API_SET=printtrace;tracefile c:\mypath\mytrace.log
ING_SET=set qep;set printqry
```

i found that this work in **dbExpres** but for some reason **not work in Firedac** any idea?